# can I override prepare for segue method in order to add some code using UIViewController extension?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I need to make a back button without title like the picture above, so instead of "< Home" bar button, I just want "<" bar button

to make it happen, I use the code like below inside prepare for segue method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // to remove title in back button in the segue destionation view controller
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }
```

But I have to put that code in so many view controller. so I thought that I can make it simpler using UIViewController extension like below

```
extension UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

        // to remove title in back button in the segue destionation view controller
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }

}
```

so when I call that prepare for segue again, it will automatically implement the code below without write that code again in every view controller

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: From the [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) chapter of the Swift book: *"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different text on Title and the Back Button on other View Controller for a View Controller by configuring the Navigation Item. 
[image]
If the Back Button text is empty, it automatically use the Title instead. You can put a space in the Back Button field on the Navigation Item of the previous View Controller. This way the title shown on the back button will become a space while its own title is still what you want.
[image]